# Why use Blur for Smoothing the image?

Tags: opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I am going through O'Reilly Learning OpenCV.
Book tells about using Blur (Low pass filter), dilation and erosion(Opening Morphological operator) to remove noise.

but before processing image for Opening morphological operator(i.e Erosion followed by dilation). he always does Blur ?

Why do we need to blur image before processing even when Erosion followed by dilation remove noise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a path that is almost closed but not due to noise (one pixel missing). Blurring will effectively close these paths and make the open/close operations more accurate.

Comment: You meant for like distorted images. ?

Comment: @ShashankJain well just for noisy images in general. blurring is effectively removes spikes in colors because it averages it out in an area, thus being a low pass filter